# Which Sniff for whitespace after condiftion in PHP?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm looking or a sniff, which detects:

```
if()
switch()
elseif()
```

because only

```
if ()
switch ()
elseif ()
```

is allowed!

Thanks

Comment: Thats `T_WHITESPACE` you can use `token_get_all`

Comment: Because of the CodingStandards in our company!

Comment: Hmm, i didn't find something, do you have further information?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `Squiz_Sniffs_ControlStructures_ControlSignatureSniff` for this, which accepts the following patterns:

```
try {EOL...} catch (...) {EOL
do {EOL...} while (...);EOL
while (...) {EOL
for (...) {EOL
if (...) {EOL
foreach (...) {EOL
} else if (...) {EOL
} else {EOL
```

If those signatures are not to your liking, have a look for `*_ControlSignaturesSniff` in the other namespaces.

Comment: hmm, PHP_CodeSniffer_Standards_AbstractPatternSniff does not support whitespaces, so the new lines are correct, but "if(" is still allowed